What do you think of some journals with high IF, but not famous?
As a PhD student, I always go through many journals and found out that some journals have a high IF, but mostly they achieved it because they do not publish many papers per year. One example in my field is "Advanced Composites and Hybrid Materials", the IF is over 20, but most of the papers there are not even close in quality to some top journals in this field. Do you think it is better to publish in a well known and respected journal for example with IF 5-9, or just chase a high IF journal with a very low number of publications per year. Assume that my paper is a perfect fit for both of them.

Correlating impact factor to publishing fewer papers per year seems, well, wrong. Submit the paper to the journal it best fits. Stop worrying about impact factors of journals.

Journals have reputations that don't come from IF.  What are the reputations of these journals?
